# Display multidimensional array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array,

```
Array
(
[part_number] => Array
    (
        [1] => "88888"
        [2] => "898989"
        [3] => "12312"
        [4] => "321321321"
    )

[manufacturer] => Array
    (
        [1] => "Dell"
        [2] => "Toshiba"
        [3] => "Asus"
        [4] => "AMD"
    )

[description] => Array
    (
        [1] => "i3 Processor"
        [2] => "i5 Processor"
        [3] => "i7 Processor"
        [4] => "Video Card 4GB"
    )

[list_price] => Array
    (
        [1] => "450"
        [2] => "100"
        [3] => "100"
        [4] => "150"
    )

[net_price] => Array
    (
        [1] => "500"
        [2] => "120"
        [3] => "120"
        [4] => "200"
    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [1] => "600"
        [2] => "150"
        [3] => "150"
        [4] => "80"
    )

[measure] => Array
    (
        [1] => "14 inch"
        [2] => "Pc/s"
        [3] => "Pc/s"
        [4] => "Pc/s"
       )

   )
```

and I want to display it dynamically depending on the array values.

Sample format:

```
part_number : "88888"
manufacturer : "Dell"
description : "i3 Processor"
list_price : "450"
net_price : "500"
quantity : "600"
measure : "14 inch"
```

and so on…

I'm stuck in this part.

Here's my code

```
<?php foreach($success_arr as $success_part_number => $val): ?>
    <?=$success_part_number." : ".$val[1];?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want the `val` to be dynamic. I don't know how to count the number of values return in an array.

Comment: count($myArr) will give the number of elements in $myArr.

Comment: In addition if you're trying to enumerate through the values and generate markup based on those values you can just echo your markup with the values etched in: `foreach($success_arr as $success_part_number => $val){echo '<h3>' . "$success_part_number:$val" . '</h3>'; }` or you can just remove the tags or you want to display the raw text but this will most likely not have linebreaks so you'll probably want to display them in an element for the sake of the eyes. ;)

Comment: yeah.. it's going to be put on <li> tags.. so no need for breaklines... what I want is that how can I count the values inside the part_number for example.

Answer (score 0):

You an run the foreach loop inside for loop.

```
   $counter = count($array['manufacturer']);
        for ($i=0; $i < $counter; $i++) 
        { 
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($array as $success_part_number => $val)
            {
                echo "<li>";
                echo $success_part_number." : ".$val[$i];
                echo "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "<hr>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nicely format your data in table like code bellow, but you have to make sure all inner arrays have the same length

```
echo '<table>';
// $i is your starting point - 1;
for($i = 0; $i<= count($arr['part_number']); $i++)
{
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
    // with first loop we build table headers => your inner array keys
        if($i==0) {
            echo '<th>' .$k. '</th>';
            continue;
        } 
        // start to build your data rows
        echo '<td>' . $v[$i] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```